# How to merge multiple network calls’ responses into an array? With or without Combine?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

Working with `flagpedia.net/download/api`

It has two endpoints:

1 - Returns [String:String] dictionary of code-country pairs, like [“us”:”United States”] as a json

2 - Returns an image data for a country code and specified image size, example url `flagcdn.com/16x12/us.png`

I have create two functions using regular completion handler

- `fetchCodes(completion: @escaping (Result<[String],Error>) -> Void) { … }`
- `fetchImage(forCode: String, completion: @escaping (Result<UIImage,Error>) -> Void) { … }`

And also their Combine variations

- `fetchCodes() -> AnyPublisher<[String],Error> { … }`
- `fetchImage(forCode: String) -> AnyPublisher<UIImage,Error> { … }`

Both methods works fine, and returns expected result. How could we merge them?

fetchCodes() method decodes json into dictionary and create an array from the keys.

After getting codes: [String] from fetchCodes() want to do something like this:

- `var results = [UIImage]()`
- `for code in codes {`
- `let image = fetchImage(forCode: code)`
- `images.append(image)`
- `}`

How to achieve this?

I tried Publishers.ManyMerge and flatMap but wasn’t successful. Ended up getting warning regarding mismatch in return types.

`Sorry for the indentation, I’m posting this on mobile.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a great way to do it with the Combine operators:

```
func fetchCodes() -> AnyPublisher<[String],Error> { fatalError() }
func fetchImage(forCode: String) -> AnyPublisher<UIImage,Error> { fatalError() }

func example() -> AnyPublisher<[String: UIImage], Error> {
    let codesAndImages = keysAndValues(fetchImage(forCode:))
    return fetchCodes()
        .flatMap { codes in
            combineLatest(codesAndImages(codes))
        }
        .map(Dictionary.init(uniqueKeysWithValues:))
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func keysAndValues<A, B>(_ get: @escaping (A) -> AnyPublisher<B, Error>) -> ([A]) -> [AnyPublisher<(A, B), Error>] {
    { xs in
        xs.map { x in
            Just(x).setFailureType(to: Error.self)
                .zip(get(x))
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    }
}

func combineLatest<A>(_ xs: [AnyPublisher<A, Error>]) -> AnyPublisher<[A], Error> {
    xs.reduce(Empty<[A], Error>().eraseToAnyPublisher()) { state, x in
        state.combineLatest(x)
            .map { $0.0 + [$0.1] }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

or you could do it like this which is flatter:

```
func example() -> AnyPublisher<[String: UIImage], Error> {
    fetchCodes()
        .map { codes in
            codes.map { Just($0).setFailureType(to: Error.self).zip(fetchImage(forCode: $0)) }
        }
        .flatMap { zip($0) }
        .map(Dictionary.init(uniqueKeysWithValues:))
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func zip<Pub>(_ xs: [Pub]) -> AnyPublisher<[Pub.Output], Pub.Failure> where Pub: Publisher {
    xs.reduce(Empty<[Pub.Output], Pub.Failure>().eraseToAnyPublisher()) { state, x in
        state.zip(x)
            .map { $0.0 + [$0.1] }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Without Combine it gets a bit more tricky:

```
func fetchCodes(completion: @escaping (Result<[String],Error>) -> Void) { }
func fetchImage(forCode: String, completion: @escaping (Result<UIImage,Error>) -> Void) { }

func example(_ completion: @escaping (Result<[String: UIImage], Error>) -> Void) {
    fetchCodes { codesResult in
        switch codesResult {
        case let .success(codes):
            loadImages(codes: codes, completion)
        case let .failure(error):
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
}

func loadImages(codes: [String], _ completion: @escaping (Result<[String: UIImage], Error>) -> Void) {
    var result = [String: UIImage]()
    let lock = NSRecursiveLock()
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    for code in codes {
        group.enter()
        fetchImage(forCode: code) { imageResult in
            switch imageResult {
            case let .success(image):
                lock.lock()
                result[code] = image
                lock.unlock()
                group.leave()
            case let .failure(error):
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion(.success(result))
    }
}
```

With the Combine version if a fetchImage fails, then the others are all canceled. With the callback version, that is not the case. Instead, the others will finish and then throw away the data downloaded.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. The following part was giving an error, had to pass it directly:
let codesAndImages = keysAndValues(fetchImage(forCode:))

Comment: Then you didn't give enough information. The code I posted in the answer compiles fine.

Comment: I added another method of doing the Publisher version.